# How do I adjust bone rotation_mode when freshly created armature has pose = None (python)

Tags: python, armature

I am creating a lot of armatures using python.  One of the things I need to do is set the `rotation_mode` on all the bones to be `'XYZ'` instead of `'QUATERNION'`.

Unfortunately the following (super-trimmed-down) code malfunctions:

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('garbage', bpy.data.armatures['lids_armature.007'])
scn.objects.link(obj)

obj.pose.bones[0].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thoth/art/mehndi/mehndi.blend/garbage", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bones'
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

What is the proper python technique for setting the bones' `rotation_mode` immediately after creation?

Comment: put a scene update in there after the link.  `scn.update()`

Answer (score 1):

LucaRood in IRC was the first one to suggest using `scn.update()` after the `link()`.  batFINGER and my testing agree with that solution.  So the proper code would be

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('garbage', bpy.data.armatures['lids_armature.007'])
scn.objects.link(obj)

scn.update()
obj.pose.bones[0].rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
```